How close can I set a post to the base of a retaining wall?
Any recommendations how close you can put a post (4”x4”) which will be 2 feet deep in the ground and close to retaining wall? The wall is just 1 year old.
I am going to build 3 sides of fence to cover my raised garden bed. One side will be covered by the wall. I have to install posts at both ends of the wall. So how close without bothering structure and integrity of the wall?

The wall almost built as per the picture below.

do you have any design drawings for the wall? ... specifically something that provides information about the wall foundation

place the post a couple of feet away from the wall ... place a custom made fence panel between the post and the retaining wall ... use hinges to attach the panel to the post ... the panel does not need to touch the retaining wall

Just added a similar drawing not exact used by my contractor. I have already added another question if is it fine to build raise garden beds 2 feet away from then wall. Thought it’s a silly question, but better than sorry.

Do you mean you're going to build 3 sides of wall using the existing retaining wall as the 4th wall to retain the soil for your raised bed?  A fence is typically something that sticks up above ground on both sides.

There's not really a good way to assess this from a photo. It depends on the construction of the wall's foundation and the surrounding soil integrity. Here's what I'd do.

Put the first post 16-24" from the wall. You can extend the fence rails past that post to reach the wall and close the gap with most fence styles. If you're using pre-built panels, simply set the second post accordingly.

As you dig, observe. Note whether the hole wall is sloughing off, or if anything related to the wall appears to be moving. If so, stop immediately and backfill, compacting as you go.

Once you have your hole dug, expedite backfill. Get the job done in a day, if possible, and don't keep the hole open during rain events. Compact well in lifts.

Keep any disturbance of the surrounding ground to a minimum. Don't drive machinery near the hole. Don't allow children to play nearby.


